# Powershell Network Device Info

Tags: powershell, networking, windows-10

I am making a Powershell CmdLet, and one function is getting info from network devices

I just want it to output the device hostname, and weather or not the device has connectivity.

Here's my current code:

```
$devlist = arp -a

    $devlength = $devlist.Length - 1

foreach($i in 3..$devlength){
    $devlist[$i] = $devlist[$i].Substring(0,24) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ' ','' }
    ping -n 1 -a $devlist[$i]
}
```

I want the output format to be something like this:

Device host name (if received) | Device IP address | Has connectivity (yes/no)

Comment: What doesn't work? How does it not work? Please post the code you currently have (properly formatted), and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: Can you update your post with that code

Comment: is there a reason to NOT use powershell to gather the info you are trying to parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something a long the lines of:

```
(arp -a | Select-Object -skip 10).Trim() -replace "(\s+){3}",","  |
    ConvertFrom-Csv | 
    ForEach-Object -Process `
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            IPAddress = $_.{Internet Address}
            HostName  = (Resolve-DnsName $_.{Internet Address} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).NameHost
            Status    = if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.{Internet Address} -Count 1 -Quiet) {'Online'} else {'Offline'}
        }       

    }
```

I took the approach as converting the entirety of the returned values, as an object to make it easier to work with.

**EDIT**:
If you're looking to make this accessible to other users, you have to account on how their Arp Table is set, and how many interfaces there are. So attempting to guess where the column headers start, is not the best solution. So here's what you can do to get around that:

```
((arp -a).Trim().Where{$_ -match "^\d+"}) -replace "\s+","," | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Header "IPAddress","MACAddress","Type" |
    ForEach-Object -Process `
        {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                IPAddress = $_.IPAddress
                HostName  = (Resolve-DnsName $_.IPAddress -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).NameHost
                Status    = if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.IPAddress -Count 1 -Quiet) {'Online'} else {'Offline'}
            }       
        }
```

- Returning **just** IP's, you can narrow down the selection of what will be converted to a *csv*.
- Then, adding your own headers will allow you to have all interfaces combined into one *csv* that we can convert into objects.

Comment: This just throws an error:

Resolve-DnsName : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or 
empty, and then try the command again.

Comment: That's because my `arp -a` results are different than yours. I had to skip 10 lines to get the addresses as I'm on VPN.  So run `arp -a` and see where the column headers of Internet Address and the rest start. Then skip to that line, or don't if it's not needed.

Comment: It Worked!!!
I just had to change the value to 2
Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Very cool man! Happy to help!:) and oops! i forgot to include the property (IP Address) to ping! Just updated the code! Changed `Test-Connection -ComputerName $_` to `Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.{Internet Address}`

Comment: Yes, thank you!
Now it correctly displays the connectivity status
Also, I piped this script into format-list for logging to a file and it looks good

Comment: @Coolcreeper, see my edit.

Comment: Thank you, now it works on both of my computers! (one uses a vpn)